# Avoiding having Swing Highlighters spill into newly added text

Tags: java, swing

I am implementing a simple highlighter over a `JTextPane`. I want it to highlight special keywords such as `if`, `case`, etc as I type them. As IDEs do.

The problem I'm facing is that when I detect a special keyword was just written and I highlight it (this does work well) then everything I type afterwards is also highlighted. Looking at the API I would assume this would not be the case. How to avoid this?

Here's the offending code:

```
if (word.equals("if")) {                        
    textPane.getHighlighter().addHighlight(wordStartIdx, pos+1, highlightPainter);
    textPane.getHighlighter().addHighlight(pos+2, pos+2, noHightlighter); // tried this to see if it would help, but it doesn't change anything.. anything typed after the word "if" will still be hightlighted!
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a Highlighter you can try using attributes:

```
SimpleAttributeSet green = new SimpleAttributeSet();
StyleConstants.setForeground(green, Color.GREEN);

//  Change attributes on some existing text

StyledDocument doc = textPane.getStyledDocument();
int offset = textPane.getCaretPosition(); // should be after the "f"
doc.setCharacterAttributes(offset-2, 2, green, false);
```

Comment: I read about attribute sets and wondered -- what are the pros/cons of using highlighters vs attribute sets? They seem to be similar in what they offer.